# Adding First & Last Page to my Pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Pagination code that only displays the page numbers, such as 1, 2, 3 etc. I would like to add First page, last page & next/previous page buttons. I am dynamically displaying a list of cards.

I am aware that there are similar questions, however most use queries to receive the number of cards to display. I do not wish to use that

My code:

```
pageSize = 8;

    var pageCount =  $(".card").length / pageSize;
    
     for(var i = 0 ; i<pageCount;i++){
        
       $("#pagin").append('<li><a href="#">'+(i+1)+'</a></li> ');
     }
        $("#pagin li").first().find("a").addClass("current")
    showPage = function(page) {
        
        $(".card").hide();
        $(".card").each(function(n) {
            if (n >= pageSize * (page - 1) && n < pageSize * page)
                $(this).show();
        });        
    }
    
    showPage(1);

    $("#pagin li a").click(function() {
        $("#pagin li a").removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");
        showPage(parseInt($(this).text())) 
    });
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="pagin" class="pagination pagination-lg justify-content-center"></ul>
```